# Bug in OS X 10.5 malloc?

Tags: c, crash, malloc

I'm writing a program in C.  I have two main development machines, both Macs.  One is running OS X 10.5 and is a 32bit machine, the other is running OS X 10.6 and is 64 bits.  The program works fine when compiled and run on the 64bit machine.   However, when I compile the exact same program on the 32bit machine it runs for a while and then crashes somewhere inside `malloc`.  Here's the backtrace:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0xeeb40fe0
0x9036d598 in small_malloc_from_free_list ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x9036d598 in small_malloc_from_free_list ()
#1  0x90365286 in szone_malloc ()
#2  0x903650b8 in malloc_zone_malloc ()
#3  0x9036504c in malloc ()
#4  0x0000b14c in xmalloc (s=2048) at Common.h:185
...
```

`xmalloc` is my custom wrapper which just calls `exit` if `malloc` returns `NULL`, so it's not running out of memory.

If I link the same code with `-ltcmalloc` it works fine, so I strongly suspect that it's a bug somewhere inside OS X 10.5's default allocator.  It may be that my program is causing some memory corruption somewhere and that `tcmalloc` somehow doesn't get tripped up by it.  I tried to reproduce the failure by doing the same sequence of `malloc`s and `free`s in a different program but that worked fine.

So my questions are:

- Has anyone seen this bug before?   Or, alternatively
- How can I debug something like this?  E.g., is there a debug version of OS X's `malloc`?

BTW, these are the linked libraries:

```
$ otool -L ./interp 
./interp:
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.5)
```

**Update**: Yeah, it's heap corruption due to writing past the end off an array, it's working now.  I should have run `valgrind` before posting the question.  I was nevertheless interested in techniques (other than valgrind) how to protect from such kind of corruption, so thanks for that.

Comment: "so I strongly suspect that it's a bug somewhere inside OS X 10.5's default allocator": No it's not.  You're corrupting memory somewhere.  Have you tried running under valgrind?

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug in your program corrupting the heap.

Comment: It *could* be a bug in `malloc`, but remember: when a developer says "I suspect there's a bug in a library", there's a 90% chance they're wrong.  (Similarly, when a library writer says "I suspect there's a bug in the kernel", there's a 90% chance they're wrong; when a kernel engineer says "I suspect there's a bug in the hardware", there's a 90% chance they're wrong, too).  In this case, it looks like your code is stomping on one of malloc's internal data structures; because tcmalloc has different internal data structures, using it avoids the issue.

Comment: this is known as wishful thinking

Comment: @stephen: for something as fundamental as malloc, I'd say the odds are MUCH higher than 90%. Reminds me of a "programmer" who "discovered" (and reported) a "bug" in strcat, not knowing the destination needed the space to hold results of concatenation.

Comment: @xcramps: Oh, I know, I was being very conservative (the actual number is more like 99.99%).  And @nominolo: I say all this with the utmost sympathy, as someone who has (a) made such proclamations and (b) uncovered legitimate bugs in libraries, kernels, and hardware.

Comment: In my programming career, I have discovered hundreds of bugs that were absolutely guaranteed, no doubt at all bugs in libc, the compiler, the operating system, the hardware etc.  In every single case bar one, they eventually turned out to be "libc/the compiler/the operating system fails to deal with stupidity in code by jeremyp".  The one exception was a code generation bug in the Burroughs CTOS Pascal compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read the manual page for `malloc()` on MacOS X?  In part, it says:

#### DEBUGGING ALLOCATION ERRORS

> A number of facilities are provided to aid in debugging allocation errors in applications.  These
>    facilities are primarily controlled via environment variables.  The recognized environment variables
>        and their meanings are documented below.

#### ENVIRONMENT

> The following environment variables change the behavior of the allocation-related functions.
>
> - `MallocLogFile <f>`
>
>   Create/append messages to the given file path  instead of writing to
>                                   the standard error.
> - MallocGuardEdges
>
>   If set, add a guard page before and after each large block.
> - MallocDoNotProtectPrelude
>
>   If set, do not add a guard page before large blocks, even if the
>                                   MallocGuardEdges environment variable is set.
> - MallocDoNotProtectPostlude
>
>   If set, do not add a guard page after large blocks, even if the
>                                   MallocGuardEdges environment variable is set.
> - MallocStackLogging
>
>   If set, record all stacks, so that tools like leaks can be used.
> - MallocStackLoggingNoCompact
>
>   If set, record all stacks in a manner that is compatible with the
>                                   malloc_history program.
> - MallocStackLoggingDirectory
>
>   If set, records stack logs to the directory specified instead of saving
>                                   them to the default location (/tmp).
> - MallocScribble
>
>   If set, fill memory that has been allocated with 0xaa bytes.  This
>                                   increases the likelihood that a program making assumptions about the contents of freshly allocated memory will fail.  Also if set, fill memory
>                                   that has been deallocated with 0x55 bytes.  This increases the likelihood
>                                   that a program will fail due to accessing memory that is no longer allocated.
> - `MallocCheckHeapStart <s>`
>
>   If set, specifies the number of allocations `<s>` to wait before begining
>                                   periodic heap checks every `<n>` as specified by MallocCheckHeapEach.  If
>                                   MallocCheckHeapStart is set but MallocCheckHeapEach is not specified, the
>                                   default check repetition is 1000.
> - `MallocCheckHeapEach <n>`
>
>   If set, run a consistency check on the heap every `<n>` operations.
>                                   MallocCheckHeapEach is only meaningful if MallocCheckHeapStart is also
>                                   set.
> - `MallocCheckHeapSleep <t>`
>
>   Sets the number of seconds to sleep (waiting for a debugger to attach)
>                                   when MallocCheckHeapStart is set and a heap corruption is detected.  The
>                                   default is 100 seconds.  Setting this to zero means not to sleep at all.
>                                   Setting this to a negative number means to sleep (for the positive number
>                                   of seconds) only the very first time a heap corruption is detected.
> - `MallocCheckHeapAbort <b>`
>
>   When MallocCheckHeapStart is set and this is set to a non-zero value,
>                                   causes abort(3) to be called if a heap corruption is detected, instead of
>                                   any sleeping.
> - MallocErrorAbort
>
>   If set, causes abort(3) to be called if an error was encountered in
>                                   malloc(3) or free(3) , such as a calling free(3) on a pointer previously
>                                   freed.
> - MallocCorruptionAbort
>
>   Similar to MallocErrorAbort but will not abort in out of memory conditions, making it more useful to catch only those errors which will cause
>                                   memory corruption.  MallocCorruptionAbort is always set on 64-bit processes.

---

That said, I'd still use `valgrind` first.

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone seen this bug before

Yes, this is common programming bug and is almost certainly in your code. See http://www.efnetcpp.org/wiki/Heap_Corruption

> How can I debug something like this?

See the Tools section of the above link.